# Creating/Registering a PySpark UDF and apply it to one column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am just a little confused on how to create the spark udf. I have right now a function `parse_xml` and do the following:

```
spark.udf.register("parse_xml_udf", parse_xml)
parsed_df = xml_df.withColumn("parsed_xml", parse_xml_udf(xml_df["raw_xml"]))
```

where `xml_df` is the original spark df and `raw_xml` is the column I want to apply the function on.

I have seen a few places a line like `spark_udf = udf(parse_xml, StringType())` -- what is the difference between this and the `spark.udf.register` line? Additionally, if I apply the function to that one column, is it applying it to each row? In other words, should my UDF be returning the output for one single row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- This `spark.udf.register("squaredWithPython", squared)` if you want to use with **SQL** like this: `%sql select id, squaredWithPython(id) as id_squared from test`
- This `squared_udf = udf(squared, LongType())` if just with **data frame usage** like this: `display(df.select("id", squared_udf("id").alias("id_squared")))`

That's all, but things not always clearly explained in the manuals.

Comment: So if I want to use it like this: `xml_df.withColumn('parsed_xml', parse_xml_udf(xml_df['raw_xml']))`, I need to do it as `udf(__)`?

Comment: Yes, withColumn will apply to all rows unless you filter them.

Comment: But do I need the `spark.udf.register()` line? Or just the `udf()` line? Or both?

Comment: Can do both, and see which works and learn...UDF should be enough, but try depends how you call, Spark has all sorts of quirks

Comment: Ok thanks! So my code from the question looks okay?

Comment: yep from this distance

Comment: Thanks for the help.